# Can't access postgres console

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I have postgres installed on a macbook. I have been able to access it in the past but now I get an error if I attempt to access the postgres console. If I run, `launchctl list | grep postgres` I get "-   -6  homebrew.mxcl.postgresql"

If I run `psql postgres` I get
"psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?"

I have attempted to stop and start postgres but I get another error: `brew services start postgresql`
Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/core/postgresql".
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap homebrew/core

Any suggestions to fix this?